# Scala : Dataframe Merge

Tags: scala, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes in scala, i created them using the sql queries via hive context, please see the df as images here
[image: demand_df]

Another dataframe is as
[image: skill_map]

Please ignore the repetition of headers in second df, i want to compare the Skill column present in both the data frames and get the equivalent Role, Skill2  and emerging in df1 i.e. demand_df,

I tried this in pandas and was able to achieve by using the following code segment

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    ["INDIA", "XXX","developer","UNKNOWN",121],
    ["INDIA", "XXXX","software engineer","UNKNOWN",121],
    ["POLAND","XX","english","KNOWN",12‌​2]], 
    columns=['country', 'level','Skill','r2d2','tax']) 

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    ["english", "NaN","teacher","NaN","NaN"],
    [20000,"Unknown","NaN","NaN","N‌​aN"],
    ["microsoft","K‌​nown","Software Engineer","Microsoft","Enterprise"]], 
    columns=['Skill', 'R2D2','Role','Skill2','Emerging'])

result= df1.merge(df2[['Skill','Role','Skill2','emerging']], how = 'left', left_on = 'Skill', right_on = 'Skill')
```

Please guide me,as I am new to scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have created two dataframes and want to join two on the basis of skill and create a new dataframe which has df1 and  Role, Skill2 and emerging from df2. 
You can do it through sqlcontext. 
 **val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)**

register both dataframe as temptable with the command :

**df1.registerTempTable("df1")**

**df2.registerTempTable("df2")**

after that you use simple hive query to join and fetch the required columns from data frame :

val df3 = sqlContext.sql("select a.*,b.* from df1 a left join df2 b on (a.skill = b.skill)")

Comment: Thanks @kishan singh , this served my purpose.